# Use of the word "terrestrial" as "something easier to understand"

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, informal-writing

I know that the word *terrestrial* originally meant something relating to the earth. But I think I've heard it being used before meaning something *close to home* or *easier to understand* in the context of mathematics. I can't remember the exact phrase, but I think it was used like this:

> Let's break it down to something more simple and terrestrial.

I got curious, so I searched the internet for this definition, but there seems to be no mention of it.

Am I wrong in understanding this word this way?

Comment: I've never encountered this, but I might recognize it as a variation on the idiom *down to earth*.

Comment: Sounds like a mistranslation of "down to earth" rather than a variation of it.

Comment: It may relate to wider context eg simplifying cosmology. Some kind of metaphor or creative imagery.

Comment: There's no such expression, so I'd say the speaker was making a bit of a joke, and it seems you understood it perfectly so it worked.

Comment: Maybe you meant *pedestrian*?

Comment: @PhilSweet It could have been pedestrian. I heard it on a video on YouTube, so I could have misheard it somehow.

Comment: _Pedestrian_ has the right meaning, in context, **and** it has the same syllabic, stress, and vowel structures as _terrestrial_, so it could be easily mistaken. Case closed.

Comment: Given the right context, I could understand that as *terrestrial* (which is what you heard), as meaning the opposite of something so outlandish and foreign sounding, that one might react to it as though it came from an extraterrestrial, such as a Martian.

Comment: So far we have down to earth, literal, joke, pedestrian, and anti-extraterrestrial. I am amazed how rich in interpretation the English language can be.
I guess I'll never know the true answer, but thank you all for answering!

Comment: Should I somehow close this question? Or should I leave it be?

Comment: No, never… but how would 'mundane' or 'worldly' not work? Either way, in my view word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP acknowledges in a comment that the word might have been "pedestrian". If it was "pedestrian", then this question serves no purpose. If it was "terrestrial", then it was probably either a nonstandard use of the word or the meaning that alphabet suggested, which is easy to look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As MW states, "terrestrial" can mean:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terrestrial)

> mundane in scope or character; prosaic